# How can I show a vector of labels with bold and normal font on a plot?

Tags: r, vector, text, plot, fonts

I would like to add text labels to a plot that contain both bold and normal font for several labels that are stored in a vector.

While I managed to do that for a single label (shown in green in the example plot below), I failed when I have several labels that I'd like to show with a single text call (shown in red in the plot).

Here is an example which creates the plot below:

```
plot(0,ylim=c(1,10),xlab="",ylab="",xaxt="n",yaxt="n")

mylabels <- c("Some text in bold: normal text", "Some other text in bold: more normal text")
text(x=rep(1, 2), y=c(10,9), labels=mylabels)

# change labels to show bold font before the colon and normal behind
mylabels.bold <- gsub("$","')", gsub(":", "'), ':", gsub("^","paste(bold('", mylabels)))
#> mylabels.bold
#[1] "paste(bold('Some text in bold'), ': normal text')"           
#[2] "paste(bold('Some other text in bold'), ': more normal text')"

# this works
text(x=1, y=8, labels=parse(text=mylabels.bold[1]), col="green")

# this doesn't
parsetext <- function(x) { parse(text=x) }
text(x=rep(1, 2), y=c(7,6), labels=lapply(mylabels.bold,parsetext), col="red")
```

[image: example with labels in bold and normal font]

So the question is: How can I get the red text looking like the green?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way to do this. So, instead of trying to loop in the labels argument you can loop outside so that you add the labels one by one.

```
plot(0, ylim=c(1,10), xlab="", ylab="", xaxt="n", yaxt="n")
xs <- rep(1, 2)
ys <- c(6, 7)
for (i in seq_along(mylabels.bold)) {
  text(x = xs[i], y = ys[i], labels = parse(text=mylabels.bold[1]), col = "red")
}
```

Another solution would be to do:

```
plot(0,ylim=c(1,10),xlab="",ylab="",xaxt="n",yaxt="n")
parsetext <- function(x) { parse(text=x) }
text(x=rep(1, 2), y=c(7,6), labels=sapply(mylabels.bold,parsetext), col="red")
```

If you read the documentation of `?text` you will see that labels need to be a character vector or expression. `lapply` creates a list and this is why it fails. `sapply` on the other hand creates a vector and works.

Out:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this indeed works. Still I would be interested to see a solution with lapply(); or to understand why lapply doesn't work in my above example. Anybody?

Comment: I updated my answer. `lapply` does not work because `labels` argument needs to be a character vector. However, `lapply` creates a list so it doesn't work. I changed that to `sapply` which produces a character vector and now it works.